# Extract Keywords with the # in front of the characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

i would like your help to share your insights on this. What i try to achieve here is to extract the whatever hashtag with the keywords in the sentence. I try to use regextract formula but seems like my intelligence is severely limited

##### Retreive the Four # with keywords in the following sentence which the keywords will always come with the # at the initial and following by comma ",", but the last one keywords will goes without comma ",":

`sentence sentence sentence sentence sentence sentence sentence #Blue,#Black,#Yellow,#Green John:sample sample sample // sample sample sample Alia: sample sample sample // sample sample sample`

##### End Results:

`#Blue,#Black,#Yellow,#Green`

Here is the trix if you would like to work on the file  directly **[here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzDAwti4xnXVgJNfW2q1mrsha01yBkK_skTE_Xgb-uA/edit?usp=sharing)**

---

| Data | Results that i want to achieve |
| --- | --- |
| sample:sample sample sample // sample sample sample #Blue,#Black,#Yellow,#Black John:sample sample sample // sample sample sample Alia: sample sample sample // sample sample sample | #Blue,#Black,#Yellow,#Black |
| sample:sample sample sample // sample sample sample #Blue,#Yellow John:sample sample sample // sample sample sample Alia: sample sample sample // sample sample sample | #Blue,#Yellow |

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't self contained. [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this**

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "#.+"),""))
```

[image]